# Stored procedure to update different columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have an API that i'm trying to read that gives me just the updated field. I'm trying to take that and update my tables using a stored procedure. So far the only way I have been able to figure out how to do this is with dynamic SQL but i would prefer to not do that if there is a way not to.

If it was just a couple columns, I'd just write a proc for each but we are talking about 100 fields and any of them could be updated together. One ticket might just need a timestamp updated at this time, but the next ticket might be a timestamp and who modified it while the next one might just be a note.

Everything I've read and have been taught have told me that dynamic SQL is bad and while I'll write it if I have too, I'd prefer to have a proc.

Answer (score 0):

YOU CAN PERHAPS DO SOMETHING LIKE THIS:::

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM NEWTABLE NOT IN (SELECT * FROM OLDTABLE))
BEGIN
UPDATE OLDTABLE
   SET OLDTABLE.OLDRECORDS = NEWTABLE.NEWRECORDS
   WHERE OLDTABLE.PRIMARYKEY= NEWTABLE.PRIMARYKEY
END
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve your problem is using [`MERGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql):

> Performs insert, update, or delete operations on a target table based on the results of a join with a source table. For example, you can synchronize two tables by inserting, updating, or deleting rows in one table based on differences found in the other table.

As you can see your update could be more complex but more efficient as well. Using `MERGE` requires some proficiency, but when you start to use it you'll use it with pleasure again and again.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how your business logic works that determines what columns are updated at what time.  If there are separate business functions that require updating different but consistent columns per function, you will probably want to have individual `update` statements for each function.  This will ensure that each process updates only the columns that it needs to update.

On the other hand, if your API is such that you really don't know ahead of time what needs to be updated, then building a dynamic SQL query is a good idea.

Another option is to build a save proc that sets every user-configurable field.  As long as the calling process has all of that data, it can call the save procedure and pass every updateable column.  There is no harm in having a `UPDATE MyTable SET MyCol = @MyCol` with the same values on each side.

Note that even if all of the values are the same, the `rowversion` (or `timestamp`columns) will still be updated, if present.

With our software, the tables that users can edit have a widely varying range of columns.  We chose to create a single save procedure for each table that has all of the `update`-able columns as parameters.  The calling processes (our web servers) have all the required columns in memory.  They pass all of the columns on every call.  This performs fine for our purposes.